# Building query string with form fields

Tags: python, django

I have a form which sends some parameters to a view where I use this parameters as a filter in a query. The search parameters are not obligatory and when a field of the form is left blank, I do not use it as a filter criteria.

I was trying to create the string for the query but get an error: "too many values to unpack"

Any Ideas of what could be happening? Also any ideas of a simpler way to do it would also be appreciated!

My view is like this (in the dict busca, the keys are form names and values database fields as django model)

```
def index(request):

a={}
busca={'marca':'brand = ', 'modelo':'model = ', 'tamano_min':'size >= '}
for i in request.POST:
    if i in ['marca', 'modelo', 'tamano_min']:
        valor=request.POST.get(i)
        a[i]=str.join(busca[i], valor)

query=list(a.values)
query=' and '.join(query)
latest_products = products.objects.filter(query, )

template = loader.get_template('search/index.html')
context = {'latest_products': latest_products}
return render(request, 'search/index.html', context)
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Don't reinvent the wheel by constructing your own query and use the power of Django ORM.

For example:

```
marca = request.POST.get('marca')
modelo = request.POST.get('modelo')
tamano_min = request.POST.get('tamano_min')

latest_products = products.objects.filter(brand=marca, model=modelo, size__gte=tamano_min)
```

[`get()`](https://docs.python.org/2/library/stdtypes.html#dict.get) helps to get the value of `POST` parameter or `None` if no parameter found in the dictionary. 
[`__gte`](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/dev/ref/models/querysets/#gte) ending helps to add `>=` condition.

You may also want to check `marca`, `modelo` and `tamano_min` before using them:

```
latest_products = products.objects.all()
if marca is not None:
    latest_products = latest_products.filter(brand=marca)
```

And so on.

Comment: the issue is when one of those fields are left empty... if I have brand="" it will return the ones with no brand instead of all brands... also what the_gte after size means? thanks for the help!

Comment: I can check it before, but in case it is non existent, can I use something like brand=* to select all brands? otherwise I have the same problem because I have brand=marca and if marca is non existent I still have it in my query... and thanks again!

Comment: @user2950162 this is what if already does here. If you don't include `brand=` condition, you'll get all brands. See, you first make `latest_products = products.objects.all()`, then add filters on it.

Comment: so I would get all and then filter for each parameter like you did for marca?

Comment: @user2950162 yup, and since django querysets are "lazy" it wouldn't make an actual query to the database until iterated over or evaluated.